# Stop screenshots on my macbook appearing on my ipad

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, screen-capture

I often take screenshots or partial screenshots on my MacBook.

For some reason, these immediately appear on my iPad - the screen turns on showing them, and they are stored on there.

This is annoying. I want it to stop.

So... Any ideas how I can prevent this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably universal clipboard as described in [Use Universal Clipboard to copy and paste between your Apple devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209460):

> The content is automatically added to the clipboard of your other
> nearby device. It remains there briefly, or until you replace it by
> copying something else on either device.

It also mentioned in last paragraph of [Take a screenshot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361):

> To copy a screenshot to the Clipboard, press and hold the Control key
> while you take the screenshot. You can then paste the screenshot
> somewhere else. Or use Universal Clipboard to paste it on another
> Apple device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had guessed this too... However, handoff is not activated in either my Macbook or my iPad. However, the screenshots are still copied. Nothing else is copied, however.

Comment: Simplest way to prevent universal clipboard should be turning off Handoff on either of devices.

Comment: Yes. Both turned off. Still happening!

Comment: Try logging in/out of icloud on your mac and see what happens then?

Comment: What a big bug by Apple, still not resolved till today.

Comment: Now there is no away to turn it on.